# Get array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array in PHP (like example) and I need to get the value tipo from the index, whitch is the first parameter, codigo_tipo. I tried a lot of times, but no one works. Thanks.

```
$this->conteudo['tipos'] = array(array('codigo_tipo' => '0', 'tipo' => 'Notícias'), array('codigo_tipo' => '1', 'tipo' => 'Informativos'), array('codigo_tipo' => '2', 'tipo' => 'Agenda'));
```

Comment: Post some code that you have tried...

Comment: I do not understand what you would like to do. What should the expected result look like?

Comment: I want to pass the parameter (codigo_tipo) and get the value (tipo). Got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$search = 0; // codigo_tipo

foreach ($this->conteudo['tipos'] as $key => $value)
{
  if ($value['codigo_tipo'] == $search)
  {
    echo $value['tipo']; // Noticias
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested array there, so you need to address each step separately.

```
$this->conteudo['tipos'][0]['tipo']; // <-- 'Noticias'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but this iterates through the array:

```
<?php
$this->conteudo['tipos'] = array(array('codigo_tipo' => '0', 'tipo' => 'Notícias'), array('codigo_tipo' => '1', 'tipo' => 'Informativos'), array('codigo_tipo' => '2', 'tipo' => 'Agenda'));

foreach ($this->conteudo['tipos'] as $elem) {
   echo "codigo_tipo: ".$elem['codigo_tipo']."  -  tipo: ".$elem['tipo']."\n";
}
?>
```